# How can I convert a (long) date into a readable format in C?

Tags: c, date

I am trying to convert an long date to a readable format as

```
void ConvertToDateTime(unsigned long dateTime, char *result)
{
    uint8_t day = dateTime % 100;
    uint8_t month = (dateTime / 100) % 100;
    uint8_t year = dateTime / 10000;

    sprintf(result,
            "%02u/%02u/%04u",
            day,
            month,
            year);
}
```

The caller method...

```
char *readableDateTime = (char*)"";
ConvertToDateTime(atoi(datestring), readableDateTime);
```

While debugging the datetime parameter is `20191112` (yyyymmdd) but the `result` is

`null` | `empty string` | `nada` if you prefer.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is dateTime valid and is result a valid pointer that can hold all the data resulting from sprintf?

Comment: Your code writes to a 1-byte readonly area of memory.  This is more likely to crash the program than do anything useful.  Use `char readableDateTime[100] = "";`.

Comment: An 8-bit unsigned integer can only hold values 0..255.  Note that 2019 % 256 is 227.

Comment: All three of `day`, `month`, and `year` should be plain `int`.  There's no reason to make them a smaller type; it's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code writes to a 1-byte readonly area of memory. This is more likely to crash the program than do anything useful. Use:

```
char readableDateTime[100] = "";
```

Also, an 8-bit unsigned integer can only hold values 0..255. Note that 2019 % 256 is 227.  Use at least `uint16_t` for `year`.